# Drag element, keep click event

Tags: javascript, events

I need to properly process both 'mousedown' and 'click' events. On 'mousedown' and then 'mousemove' I need to create and move a draggable element (which I already implemented). On 'click' I need to do different things. Problem is that when I click, 'mousedown' is fired first and dragging process commenced. I know I can use a flag to check, but I can't figure out the right sequence.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: `mousedown` is probably fired first because you added it first to the element

Comment: @a.mola, yes, I know the sequence of events fired. I need to figure out the right way to make them work.

Comment: You should look at this [Order of Touch and Mouse Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Supporting_both_TouchEvent_and_MouseEvent#event_order)

Comment: Like I already said, I know the sequence of events.

Comment: How about, you run the `click` function on `mousedown` and then you at the end of the `click` function, you call the `mousedown` function

Comment: This is not an option. I have several tabs with the contents below them. On tab click I need to simply switch the corresponding content. But when you click on the tab and start moving, it should become a modal window, which you can move anywhere you want (drag). So for now I can either implement click or drag.